# Use max-width while inside inline-block element

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout with one fixed column and one column of variable size with a min-width and a max-width. The columns should be flush with each other so there is no space.

An image of what I'm looking for https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLzIZ.jpg

Here's what I tried

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49krdtf6/4/

```css
.superOuter
{
  background-color:#C0C0F0;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
.outer
{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#F0C0C0;
}
.test
{
  overflow:hidden;
  min-width:100px;
  max-width:400px;
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
  padding:20px;
}
.test2
{
  float:right;
  width:200px;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#F0F0C0;
}
```

```html
<div class="superOuter">
    When there's not enough content:<br>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="test2">
            Fixed content
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            Rest with BFC
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="superOuter">
    I want it to look like this (that is unless the page shrinks)<br>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="test2">
            Fixed Content
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            Larger text here and it makes the whole thing go to the big size which is what I want without all the text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that my variable width column will not grow to it's max-width and is stuck at the width determined by its content.

Comment: I have clarified with a picture and better wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/retr0ron/

What I've done here is rearranged your content in the HTML-document (notice that there can't be whitespace between the divs where I removed it, otherwise you will see a small gap between them (because of how inline-elements behave).

HTML:

```
<div class="superOuter">
    When there's not enough content:<br>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="test">
            Rest with BFC
        </div><div class="test2">
            Fixed content
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="superOuter">
    I want it to look like this (that is unless the page shrinks)<br>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="test">
            Larger text here and it makes the whole thing go to the big size which is what I want without all the text
        </div><div class="test2">
            Fixed Content
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer
{
    max-width:600px;
    min-width: 380px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0C0C0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.test
{
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:100px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    padding:20px;
}
.test2
{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0F0C0;
}
```

Comment: Nope, this is quite different from what I was looking for. `.test` still won't use `max-width` and the columns wrap now :c

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, so you don't want them wrapping and you want it to always use max-width unless the page is smaller than the max-width?

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for

Comment: What are the measurements exactly you are looking for? Is the outer container a specific width?

Comment: Here's what I'm looking for. Your question made me realize the entire container is a max of `1450px` though so I might know what to do now. http://imgur.com/RQXXaoz | Here's a working example (different dimensions) with MelanciaUK's code but I dont think this is valid markup because one of the elements in the `table` is not a `table-cell` http://jsfiddle.net/49krdtf6/11/

Comment: Yeah, thanks, your question made me realize I could just add a max-width to the container. Here's the working one http://jsfiddle.net/49krdtf6/12/ It wraps but that's still workable

Comment: Glad it worked out, adding `min-width: 380px;` to `.outer` will stop the wrapping. You'll figure out how to edit this value accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display` `table` and `table-cell` to achieve this. Another difference is to discard `max-width` and go for just `width` instead.

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.superOuter {
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#C0C0F0;
}
.outer {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0C0C0;        
}
.fixed {
    display:table-cell;
    width:400px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;                
}
.fluid {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0F0C0;
}
```

```html
<div class="superOuter">
    When there's not enough content:
    <br />
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="fixed">Fixed content</div>
        <div class="fluid">Rest with BFC</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/49krdtf6/7/)

**UPDATE**

After discussing in the comments, I believe you actually have a limit for both columns `width`, one being `400px` and the other, `800px`.

Something like this:

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.superOuter {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;        
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#C0C0F0;                
}
.outer {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0C0C0;
}
.fixed {
    display:table-cell;
    width:400px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
.fluid {
    display:table-cell;
    width:800px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F0F0C0;
}
```

```html
<div class="superOuter">
    When there's not enough content:
    <br />
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="fixed">Fixed content</div>
        <div class="fluid">Rest with BFC</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/49krdtf6/9/)

Comment: max-width doesn't hold on .test (at least in Chrome). It just goes as large as it wants. I want it to stop at 400px. I'm not super familiar with the behaviour of table and table-cell. Is there some equivalent to max-width with tables I can then use to make it work?

Comment: Well, "Fixed Content" (.test2) is supposed to be fixed width, so width:200px. "Rest with BFC" (.test1) is supposed to take up the remaining space, as much as it can, until it hits max-width:400px. So that still doesn't solve it. I think I might just go with js if there's no css solution for this. Or maybe a large 400px wide hidden image to force it to stay large enough.

Comment: I've just changed the classes names to make it easier to show you my suggestion. In this case, the `fixed` column is set to `400px` wide, The `fluid` one should take up the remaining `width`.

Comment: Then in this case, `.fluid` would also need to max out at some `max-width`, which it can't do I dont think?

Comment: So you want both columns to go up to a limit?

Comment: One goes up to a limit, the other one is always one width

Comment: So... That's what you can see on my answer, no? Click on `Run code snippet` and choose `Full page`.

Comment: `.fixed`: no wider than `400px`. `.fluid`: any remaining `width` according to the container `width` - in this case, `100%`.

Comment: `.fixed` no wider than `400px`. `.fluid` any remaining `width` according to the container width, but only up to `800px`

Comment: So you can set the `width` for the container. `1200px`.

Comment: Setting `.outer` to `1200px` gives me nothing different than if I didn't set the width.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. If you know that one column can be up to `400px` and the other one, `800px`, you can just fix their `width`. Using `table-cell` will at least make them fluid if you shrink the page.

Comment: Ah, got it. I'm just not sure if a non `display:table-cell` in a `display:table` is valid markup. If I set them both to table cell then the `.fixed` doesn't actually keep a fixed width and the width of the two is proportional instead of fixed. Here's the working one. I'm most concerned with how it acts when the html box is resized horizontally
http://jsfiddle.net/49krdtf6/11/